# Do I need to dismiss a screen in Codename One (to prevent memory leaks)?

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm implementing a smartphone app using Codename One.

I notice that in order to show a screen, I implement a Form and invoke `Form.show()`.

As I progress through the screens, I realize that there is no `dismiss()` or `unshow()` method. So, I'm wondering if the previous screens are released from memory and I'm interested to know how are the memory managed.

## Edit:

or can I use `Display.getInstance().callSerially()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user navigates to a new form, it is created right then and the old one released and garbage-collected. If the user returns to that form, it will be recreated again. You shouldn't have memory problems from remnants of forms staying in memory. CN1 tries to minimize memory usage with this approach.

Comment: Correct unless you keep a pointer to that form or components within it as variables in your class. This this case the form will leak due to standard Java garbage collection behavior that's unrelated to Codename One